# Match DD/MM with GetDate() in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with Date Column contains only date & month (dd/mm), I want to compare it with GetDate()

```
   SMSFromDate       SMSToDate
    01/04             07/04
    08/04             15/04
    01/05             07/05
    08/05             15/05
    01/06             07/06
    08/06             15/06
    01/07             07/07
```

My Query is

```
    select * from table_abc
    where SMSFromDate<=CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),103)
          and SMSToDate>=CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),103)
```

But it is not giving me result as Expected

Comment: What do you get with your query?

Comment: You're giving it no choice but to compare those values as *strings*. Which means `08/10` occurs between `07/05` and `09/07`. Of course, converting in the opposite direction is also problematic - you cannot encode/use `29/02` in practice.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu **No result**, because I think where condition is not working

Comment: Those are strings, not dates, in a format that simply *can't* be ordered chronologically. You have to change either the column types to actually contain dates, or the string format to use a sortable format like `MM-DD`.

Comment: I Don't have to Compare Year, only A condition that can check if Today's date is greater than SMSFromDate & less than SMSToDate. I know in varchar it is not Possible, So am Finding a solution Where i can Compare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT convert(DATE, SMSFROMDATE + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR, 103)  AS SMSFROMDATE, 
    convert(DATE, SMSTODATE + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR), 103)   AS SMSTODATE
    FROM TABLE_ABC)
    SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN SMSFROMDATE AND SMSTODATE
```

Comment: getting this **error**  'Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed'

Comment: can you give try now. I don't have SQL Server currently with me, so unable to try it out.

Comment: Thanks @CleanBold  I tried and it Worked. Posting A correct one Below

Answer (score 0):

The Correct Query I got result from

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (
      select 
      convert(date,(SMSFROMDATE + '/' + cast(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())as varchar)),103) AS SMSFROMDATE,
      convert(date,(SMSTODATE + '/' + cast(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())as varchar)),103) AS SMSTODATE
     FROM SMSRoadMap_Master
    )
   SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN SMSFROMDATE AND SMSTODATE
```